On the equation $x^4+y^3+z^2+1=0$
Are there infinitely many triples of integers $(x,y,z)$ satisfying the equation
$$
x^4+y^3+z^2+1=0 \quad ?
$$
This is one of the simplest-looking equations (another one is famous $x^3+y^3+z^3=3$) for which this question is open. It is left open in my book https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-031-62949-5 , see also arxiv preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/2404.08518 .
Similar equations of the form $x^4+y^3=z^2+n$ has been discussed in the previous question Representing integers as sums of three powers , but, if I remember correctly, this specific equation has not been explicitely asked on Mathoverflow yet.
Examples of solutions are
x = 0, y = -1, z =  0
x = 1, y = -3, z =  5
x = 6, y = -13, z =  30
x = 11, y = -27, z =  71
x = 31, y = -147, z =  1501
x = 51, y = -203, z =  1265
x = 29, y = -5507, z =  408669
x = 1386, y = -15661, z =  388458
x = 288, y = -16957, z =  2206566
x = 1669, y = -21531, z =  1490663
x = 2239, y = -29931, z =  1297207
x = 855, y = -38051, z =  7386395
x = 2761, y = -47171, z =  6844587
x = 2237, y = -57147, z =  12711719
x = 1103, y = -84027, z =  24326849
x = 2859, y = -85547, z =  23648369
x = 949, y = -90891, z =  27387137
and so on.
Because the exponents are $(4,3,2)$, and $1/4+1/3+1/2>1$, heuristic strongly suggest infinity of solutions, but how to prove this?

does the equation z^2  = 6 + 11x^2 + 8x^4 have only a finite number of solutions?

@Derek Yes, by Siegel's theorem, because this equation describes a curve of genus $1$. (Maybe for this specific equation, there might be simpler reasons.)

Also Siegel's theorem can be used to prove that for any fixed a the equation has only finite number of integer solutions with one of the variables equal to a. Hence, in any infinite family of solutions, the absolute values of all variables must approach infinity.
